# How to show related post with category DESC (ASC) IDs of ID current post

Tags: customization, categories, loop

I have example Post 1(id-1), 2(id-2), 3(id-3), 4(id-4), 5(id-5), 6(id-6), 7(id-7), 8(id-8) ,9(id-9)... with same catergory.

> When in post 9, i need show related post 8, 7, 6
>
> When in post 8, i need show related post 7, 6, 5
>
> ...
>
> When in post 3, i need show related post 2, 1
>
> When in post 2, i need show related post 1
>
> When in post 1, don't show related post.

How can i do like this?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Is your _real_ goal to display them in order of date? The ID is not a reliable way to determine which order posts were posted in.

Comment: Order by date publish or ID are alright. Can you help me?